# Unable to access ASP.Net Core RESTAPI (Hosted As a windows Service) from different machine on the same network

Tags: networking, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I am hosting a ASP.net Core API using WindowsService, Its working fine on my local machine, But I am unable to access it on other machines on the same network.

When I am opening the EXE directly through Kestrel, then I am able to listen but when I am hosting it as a WindowsService, I am only able to listen on my local machine but not on other machines on the network.

**PS: I am running the WindowsService under my local account**

Error on Google Chrome : ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**Program.CS**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var repository = new ServiceRepository();

            var certificatePath = ConfigHelper.AppSetting("certPath");
            var certificatePassword = repository.Decrypt(ConfigHelper.AppSetting("certPass"));

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                   {
                       options.AddServerHeader = false;
                       options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 44302, listenOptions =>
                       {
                           listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
                       });
                       options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
                   });
               
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               }).UseWindowsService();
        }
```

**Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                 .AddJwtBearer(option =>
                 {
                     option.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;         //made purposly to test ssl with kestrel
                     option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                     {
                         ValidateLifetime = true,
                         ValidateIssuer = true,
                         ValidateAudience = true,
                         ValidIssuer = ConfigHelper.AppSetting("issuer"),
                         ValidAudience = ConfigHelper.AppSetting("audience"),
                         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConfigHelper.AppSetting("secretkey"))),
                         ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                     };
                 });
        
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });

            services.AddScoped<IApplication, Application>();
            services.AddScoped<IServiceRepository, ServiceRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
          
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "ServiceNS/{action}");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port was getting blocked through firewall, I had to add a inbound rule and specify the port which i was using in my application. This way firewall did not blocked my port for incoming requests.

References:

https://www.firehousesoftware.com/webhelp/FH/Content/FHEnterprise/FHEnterpriseInstallationGuide/24_StaticPort.htm